# Why do str[5], str[] = "1234" and str = malloc(5) have different sizes?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

Please consider the following declarations:

```
char str1[5];
char str2[] = "1234";
char *str3 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
```

The size of each `str` is printed:

```
printf("str1 has size %ld\n", sizeof(str1));
printf("str2 has size %ld\n", sizeof(str2));
printf("str3 has size %ld\n", sizeof(str3));
```

Output is:

```
str1 has size 5
str2 has size 5
str3 has size 8
```

I have understood that the size of a pointer is 8 bytes. In the 3 cases, `str` is a pointer, and `*str` corresponds to the first character of the string `str`: in the 3 cases, its size is 1 byte, which is the size of a `char`.

If I let the program allocate 5 bytes of memory to `str` with `char str[] =  "1234"` or `char str[5];`, the size of `str` is 5 bytes. But when I allocate 5 bytes to `char *str` with  `malloc`, the size of `str` is still 8 bytes, which is the size of a pointer. I expected the size of `str3` to correspond to the amount of memory I allocated to it with `malloc`.

Why am I wrong ?

Comment: Because the first two are arrays of five `char`s, while the last one is a pointer. It does not matter what you assign to `str3`, the result of `sizeof` is not going to change.

Comment: `sizeof` does not tell you the size of the data; just the size of the *type*. `sizeof char[5]` is `5`. `sizeof char[100]` is 100. `sizeof char *` is always 8 (on your machine);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR -- [Arrays are not pointers and vice-versa](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr)**

In your code, `str1` and `str2` are **"arrays"**, and `str3` is a **"pointer"**. Their sizes are printed according to their respective types.

- `str1` has 5 `char` elements, by definition.
- `str2` also has 5 `char` elements, initializer + null terminator.
- `str3` is a pointer, so `sizeof(str3)` === `sizeof(char *)` [*Note: this depends on your environment, it's not fixed, most common values are 8 (64-bit rach) and 4 (32-bit arch)*]

FWIW, use `%zu` to print the output of `sizeof` operator, as it is of type `size_t`.

Comment: @nounoursnoir __No, they are not__. See C-FAQ, chapter 6.

Comment: @nounoursnoir An array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element (and that happens when e.g. passing the array to a function) but it's not a pointer in itself.

Comment: oh ok that's an important thing i missed. ty for your answers

Comment: @nounoursnoir an array is a group of items of the same type that are stored each next to the other in memory (with padding between them if needed). A pointer is a variable that stores the address in memory of some data. They are totally different concepts. However, in C, in some contexts, an array can be used where a pointer is required; the address of the first element of the array is the value of this pseudo-pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the size of a pointer gives you the size of *the pointer* and not what it points to. That you get the size `8` means you are on a 64-bit system where pointers are 64 bits (8 bytes).

Arrays are fixed-sized chunks of memory, and using the `sizeof` operator on that will give you the size of that chunk.

Comment: well... Using `sizeof(*str)` outputs me `1`

Comment: @nounoursnoir Well that's because when you dereference the array it decays to a pointer to its first element, and you dereference that pointer which gives you the *value* the pointer is pointing to. In your case it's a character with the type `char`. So `sizeof(*str)` is equal to `sizeof(str[0])` which is equal to `sizeof(char)` which is specified to always be `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[]="1234"
```

has size 5 as it is syntactic sugar for `str[5] = {'1','2','3','4',0}`.

```
char str[5];
```

has size 5 as it is `sizeof(char)*5`.

and

```
char *str = ...;
```

has size 8 as it is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Compare these code snippets

```
char str2[] = "1234";
char *p = str2;
```

and

```
char *p = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
```

They have in common the following: pointer p points to the first byte of the allocated memory. In the first case the memory was allocated by the compiler and in the second case the memory was allocated by you in the heap.

To make it more clear it is better to consider similar code snippets in C++. They will look like

```
char str2[] = "1234";
char *p = str2;
```

and

```
char *p = new char[5];
```

And you will have

for the first code snippet

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( str2 ) ); // 5
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( p ) ); // 8
```

for the second code snippet

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( char[5] ) ); // 5
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( p ) ); // 8
```

The difference is that in the second case we do not have the name of the created dynamically array. So you have to use `sizeof( char[5] )` instead of `sizeof( array_name )`.